# How can I compare two class instances when the class contains functions

Tags: javascript, chai

If I have a ES6 class which contains a function two identical instances are not considered [deepEqual](http://chaijs.com/api/assert/#method_deepequal) by chai.  What is the correct way to compare instances in this situation.

For example given this class definition

```js
class Foo {
  x;

  constructor(x) {
    this.x = x;
  }

  y = () => x*2;
}
```

The first two tests pass but the third fails

```js
describe('class equality', function() {
  it('compare single instance', function() {
    var foo = new Foo(1);
    assert.deepEqual(foo, foo);
  });

  it('compare string', function() {
    assert.deepEqual(JSON.stringify(new Foo(1)), JSON.stringify(new Foo(1)));
  });

  it('compare instance', function() {
    assert.deepEqual(new Foo(1), new Foo(1));
  });
});
```

Demonstrated here (also [on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kge4suzv/) - comment out line 12 and all three tests pass:

```js
mocha.setup('bdd');

var assert = chai.assert;

class Foo {
  x;

  constructor(x) {
    this.x = x;
  }
  
  y = () => x*2;
}
  
describe('class equality', function() {
 it('compare single instance', function() {
    var foo = new Foo(1);
    assert.deepEqual(foo, foo);
  });

 it('compare string', function() {
    assert.deepEqual(JSON.stringify(new Foo(1)), JSON.stringify(new Foo(1)));
  });

 it('compare instance', function() {
    assert.deepEqual(new Foo(1), new Foo(1));
  });
});

mocha.run();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/2.3.4/mocha.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="mocha"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chai/3.4.1/chai.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/2.3.4/mocha.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please use Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) rather than fiddles. I've updated your question by copying the fiddle into a snippet for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's be clear: That's not an ES6 class. That's an ES6 (formally, ES2015+) class **plus** a *class field*. Class fields are not yet part of the language; as I write this in October 2017 they're a [Stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields). Your

```
y = () => x*2;
```

...adds an *enumerable* property to the instance via that soon-to-be-added (probably) syntax. (As does the `x;` near the top.) And it should be using `this`:

```
y = () => this.x*2;
// -------^^^^^
```

Chai is clearly comparing all *enumerable* properties even if they're functions. You can add your `y` as a *non-enumerable* property via `Object.defineProperty` (or, someday, with a [decorator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators) on the class field; right now, they're only Stage 2) in the constructor:

```
Object.defineProperty(this, "y", {
  value: () => this.x * 2
});
```

Updated snippet:

```js
mocha.setup('bdd');

var assert = chai.assert;

class Foo {
  x;

  constructor(x) {
    this.x = x;
    Object.defineProperty(this, "y", {
      value: () => this.x * 2
    });
  }
}
  
describe('class equality', function() {
 it('compare single instance', function() {
    var foo = new Foo(1);
    assert.deepEqual(foo, foo);
  });

 it('compare string', function() {
    assert.deepEqual(JSON.stringify(new Foo(1)), JSON.stringify(new Foo(1)));
  });

 it('compare instance', function() {
    assert.deepEqual(new Foo(1), new Foo(1));
  });
});

mocha.run();

console.log(new Foo(4).y());
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/2.3.4/mocha.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="mocha"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chai/3.4.1/chai.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/2.3.4/mocha.js"></script>
```

That said, `y` is a perfectly good candidate for being on the prototype instead, which also solves the problem:

```js
mocha.setup('bdd');

var assert = chai.assert;

class Foo {
  x;

  constructor(x) {
    this.x = x;
  }
  
  y() {
    return this.x * 2;
  }
}
  
describe('class equality', function() {
 it('compare single instance', function() {
    var foo = new Foo(1);
    assert.deepEqual(foo, foo);
  });

 it('compare string', function() {
    assert.deepEqual(JSON.stringify(new Foo(1)), JSON.stringify(new Foo(1)));
  });

 it('compare instance', function() {
    assert.deepEqual(new Foo(1), new Foo(1));
  });
});

mocha.run();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/2.3.4/mocha.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="mocha"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chai/3.4.1/chai.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/2.3.4/mocha.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's very helpful thank you, your second snippet is what I thought I was writing but with a shorthand definition

Comment: @JonFreedman: Ah! No, but it's an easy mistake to make. Class field notation defines "own" properties (and arrow functions that use `this` can't be used on prototypes, as they *close over* `this`).